# how to call ul list when I am clicking the td of Hospitails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi in the below code how to write the javascript function for Hospitails when I am clicking this Hospitals I want to show the unordered list value.

Expected output:
Hospitals--->onclick 
Bangalore| salem |Goa| Mangalore| Visakhapatnam |Vijawada| jaipur| Malaysia

But ul id how to call using function I am not getting

**updated html**

```
<div id="locations">
 <h1>Locations</h1>
    <div id="locations1">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr class="hospitails" onClick="">
            <td class="hospitails_class" onClick="">Hospitails</td>
            <td class="clinics_class" onClick="">Clinics</td>
            <td class="homecare_class" onClick="">Home Care</td>
            <td class="information_class" onClick="">Information Centers</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
       <div class="hospitails_loc">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Bangalore</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">salem</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Goa</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Mangalore</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Visakhapatnam</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Vijawada</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">jaipur</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Malaysia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
     <div class="clinics_loc">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lagos(Nigeria)</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
     <div class="homecare_loc">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Bangalore</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jaipur</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="information_loc">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Andhrapradesh</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Karnataka</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Goa</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Tamil Naidu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr").click(function(event) {
       alert(event.target.id+" and "+$(event.target).attr('class'));
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your click handler, add this code

```
  var locs = $('.hospitails_loc ul li a'), len = locs.length,i=0, strArr=[];
    for(;i<len;i++){
        strArr.push(locs[i].text);
    }
strArr = strArr.join('|');
alert(strArr);
```

For your new changes, it will be something like this, I havent validated, just check if any typo errors

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hospitails").click(function(event) {
var elem = $(event.target), selStr='',locs,len,i=0, strArr=[];
if(elem.hasClass('hospitails_class')){
  selStr= '.hospitails_loc ul li a';
}else if(elem.hasClass('clinics_class')){
  selStr= '.clinics_loc ul li a';
}else if(elem.hasClass('homecare_class')){
  selStr= '.homecare_loc ul li a';
}else if(elem.hasClass('information_class')){
   selStr= '.information_loc ul li a';
} 
        locs = $(selStr); len = locs.length;
    for(;i<len;i++){
        strArr.push(locs[i].text);
    }
strArr = strArr.join('|');
alert(strArr);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some example how you can do that using the `Array#map` function:

```
document.getElementById("myRow").onclick = function() {
    function getText(el){ return $(el).text() }

    var links = $('#ul_list li a'),
        names = Array.prototype.map.call(links, getText);
    alert( names );
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e0oynv0r/

Answer (score 0):

Try this..If not mistake..

```
$(function(){
  $('#myRow').on('click', function(){
    alert($('#ul_list li').text());
  });
});
```